How to correctly compose two classes in TypeScript
I have two TypeScript classes, AuditableStore and SearchableStore, both extending a base class Store. I want to create a new class called MyStore that combines the functionalities of both AuditableStore and SearchableStore.
Here are the definitions of the existing classes:
// Store.ts
export class Store<T extends { key: string }> {
  protected readonly storeOptions?: StoreOptions<T>;
  private readonly storeName: string;

  constructor(storeName: string, options?: StoreOptions<T>) {
    this.storeName = storeName;
    this.storeOptions = options;
  }

  save(data: T) {
    console.log('Save Implementation');
  }

  protected beforeSave(entity: T): T {
    console.log('Default Before Save');
    return entity;
  }

  // ...other store functions
}

// AuditableStore.ts
import { Store } from './Store';
    
export class AuditableStore<T extends { key: string }> extends Store<T> {
  protected readonly auditUser: string;

  constructor(
    storeName: string,
    options: StoreOptions<T> = {},
    auditUser: string,
  ) {
    super(storeName, options);
    this.auditUser = auditUser;
  }

  protected beforeSave(data: T): T {
    console.log('Execute some audit logic');
    return data;
  }
}

// SearchableStore.ts
import { Store } from './Store';
    
export class SearchableStore<T extends { key: string }> extends Store<T> {
  constructor(
    storeName: string,
    options: StoreOptions<T> = {},
  ) {
    super(storeName, options);
  }

  save(data: T) {
    super.save(data);
    console.log('Implement searchable logic here');
  }
}

What I Want to Achieve:
I want to create a new class called MyStore that combines both AuditableStore and SearchableStore. The goal is for MyStore to:

Use the AuditableStore logic when I call myStore.beforePersist(data)
Use the SearchableStore logic when I call myStore.save(data)
Ensure MyStore has access to all other store functions (e.g. delete, read, update)

Questions:

Is Composition the best approach here?
If so, how can I compose AuditableStore and SearchableStore into a new class MyStore while maintaining both functionalities?
What is the best approach to ensure that MyStore correctly implements and utilizes both the audit and searchable features?

Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this composition in TypeScript would be greatly appreciated! I always get a little lost when it comes to Composition in Typescript.

Composition doesn't feel like the right pattern for this scenario. The standard OOP approach would be to have two interfaces, and have your store implement those (with default implementations provided in the interface themselves if the language allows it). For TypeScript, you might want to take a look at mixins.

This question is similar to: Typescript multiple inheritance. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please define StoreOptions so that this is a [mre]. The answer here is likely going to be "use mixins" but it would be nice if we could verify that with testable code.

Thanks. I've now posted an answer that uses mixins to solve this problem.

Thanks to @Robby Cornelissen, @www.admiraalit.nl and @jcalz for all pointing me to Typescript Mixins. I'd never heard of them before.
As as been pointed out in comments, I was looking at this the wrong way, and composition was not a good fit for this scenario. I had a read through of the mixin documentation (as linked above) and I've created a very basic example of what I was trying to achieve, this time using mixins. It seems to achieve what I want it to do, but I still need to tweak it slightly, including looking at the typings for the contructor (I would prefer not to use any [].
// Store.ts
export type DataValidator<T> = (data: unknown) => T;

export interface BaseStoreItem {
  key: string;
}
export type BaseStoreConstructor<T extends BaseStoreItem> = new (...args: any[]) => Store<T>;

export interface StoreOptions<T> {
  expiry?: Date;
  validators?: DataValidator<T>[];
}

export class Store<T extends BaseStoreItem> {
  protected readonly storeOptions?: StoreOptions<T>;
  private readonly storeName: string;

  constructor(...args: any[]) {
    this.storeName = args[0];
    this.storeOptions = args[1];
  }

  save(data: T) {
    const updatedData = this.beforeSave(data);
    console.log(`Store: Saving ${JSON.stringify(updatedData)} in Store ${this.storeName}`);
  }

  read(key: string) {
    console.log(`Store: Reading value for ${key} in Store ${this.storeName}`);
  }

  protected beforeSave(entity: T): T {
    console.log("Store: Before Save");
    return entity;
  }
}

// AuditableMixin.ts
import { BaseStoreConstructor, BaseStoreItem } from "./store.js";

export function AuditableMixin<T extends BaseStoreItem, TBase extends BaseStoreConstructor<T>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class extends Base {
    protected auditUser: string;

    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);
      this.auditUser = args[2]; // Assuming auditUser is the third argument
    }

    protected beforeSave(data: T): T {
      console.log("Auditable: Execute some audit logic");
      return data;
    }
  };
}

// SearchableMixin.ts
export function SearchableMixin<T extends new(...args: any[]) => {}>(Base: T) {
  return class extends Base {
    save(data: { key: string }) {
      super.save(data);
      console.log('Implement searchable logic here');
    }
  };
}

// store.implementation.ts
import { BaseStoreItem, Store } from "./store.js";
import { SearchableMixin } from "./searchable-store.mixin.js";
import { AuditableMixin } from "./auditable-store.mixin.js";

// Compose MyStore by combining the base Store with the mixins
class MyStoreBase<T extends BaseStoreItem> extends Store<T> {}

const SearchableAndAuditableStoreMixin = AuditableMixin(SearchableMixin(MyStoreBase));
const SearchableStoreMixin = SearchableMixin(MyStoreBase);
const AuditableStoreMixin = AuditableMixin(MyStoreBase);

export interface MyStoreDetails {
  key: string;
  otherProp: boolean;
}

export class SearchableAndAuditableStore<T extends BaseStoreItem> extends SearchableAndAuditableStoreMixin<T> {
  constructor(storeName: string, options: any = {}, auditUser: string) {
    super(storeName, options, auditUser);
  }
}

export class AuditableStore<T extends BaseStoreItem> extends AuditableStoreMixin<T> {
  constructor(storeName: string, options: any = {}, auditUser: string) {
    super(storeName, options, auditUser);
  }
}

export class SearchableStore<T extends BaseStoreItem> extends SearchableStoreMixin<T> {
  constructor(storeName: string, options: any = {}) {
    super(storeName, options);
  }
}

// Searchable and Auditable Execution
const store = new SearchableAndAuditableStore<MyStoreDetails>("my-store", { validators: [] }, "TEST_USER");

store.save({ key: "test-key", otherProp: false });
store.read("test-key");
// Console Log:
// Auditable: Execute some audit logic
// Store: Saving {"key":"test-key","otherProp":false} in Store my-store
// Searchable: Implement searchable logic here
// Store: Reading value for test-key in Store my-store

// Auditable Execution
const store = new AuditableStore<MyStoreDetails>("my-store", { validators: [] }, "TEST_USER");

store.save({ key: "test-key", otherProp: false });
store.read("test-key");
// Console Log:
// Auditable: Execute some audit logic
// Store: Saving {"key":"test-key","otherProp":false} in Store my-store
// Store: Reading value for test-key in Store my-store

// Searchable Execution
const store = new SearchableStore<MyStoreDetails>("my-store", { validators: [] });

store.save({ key: "test-key", otherProp: false });
store.read("test-key");
// Console Log:
// Store: Before Save
// Store: Saving {"key":"test-key","otherProp":false} in Store my-store
// Searchable: Implement searchable logic here
// Store: Reading value for test-key in Store my-store

Mixin approach summary:
This approach seems to do what I need it to do.

Define interfaces for specific methods if needed for more strict type checking.
MyStore holds instances of AuditableStore and SearchableStore.
Methods in MyStore delegate calls to the respective methods in AuditableStore and SearchableStore.
MyStore constructor initializes the instances of AuditableStore and SearchableStore with the required parameters.

In this approach, MyStore will contain two instances of Store, each with their own values for storeOptions and storeName. How can we keep these consistent? OP wrote that MyStore shall have all functions of Store, including update. What if MyStore.update is called? Do you propose to call both AuditableStore.update and SearchableStore.update?
